# Android dex a JAR file which includes extra non .java files

Tags: android, build, jar, dex

I have a JAR library which includes some non source code files in a couple different `/src` packages (JSON files in this case) 
When I add that JAR as a dependency on one of my Android projects and build the apk file, those JSON files are not in the apk or the classes.dex (I ran `dex2jar` and saw that the files are missing)

How can I tell `dex` to also include those json files in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, a dex file is only designed to hold .class files (and strings). Here is an (old) description of the dex file format. (I was unable to find one on google's site) http://retrodev.com/android/dexformat.html

When google parses your dependency jars at compile time it only pays attention to .class files, since that is what dependencies are for - classes you want to use in your code which aren't defined in your code. I'm not sure it even pays attention to anything else you might have in those jars.

The question you want to ask is not how to tell dex to include the json files (it can't) but how to get those json files into your apk. Unfortunately, if they are stored in a jar I don't know of a way to do this short of setting up something in ant to manually unpack the jar and move the files yourself. Compile-time jar dependencies are not designed to simply copy files into your project package.

Comment: Why this "answer" is accepted? It does not provide any solution. Sometimes it's best to refrain from writing non-answer if one doesn't have the good solution

Comment: @francogrex: Well, the question as stated does not have a solution, as the DEX format does not allow for JSON files to be included. 
I did provide a potential way to do this in the final paragraph although I admit it's not a detailed explanation - it went beyond the scope of the initial question.